# Making an exe pause

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I am using main.exe for my program in C++, which then calls other executables in some situations.

How do I make an exe pause until another exe is executed?

Example:

I have an exe which creates dialog boxes for different situations (error, invalid arg, etc). Sometimes I might take an arg from the user & sometimes I might not. 
So, until I take the arg from user how do I make my main.exe pause? Also, I want the arg in another exe.

So should I use **new** for storing the arg dynamically & pass **pointers** to that memory location in whichever exe I need the arg? By doing this am I doing memory leak? I will use **delete** after my need of that arg is over.

Comment: For linux, it is fork/wait. On windows, I have no idea, but it must have something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this on Windows you need to spawn your process with `CreateProcess()` then wait on the handle that is returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure using `WaitForSingleObject`.

Just ensure that the `CreateProcess` call succeeds. Any parameters can be passed via the command line or by using shared memory or a named pipe, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Boost` (can't remember the exact library name) or you can use:

`wait` for *unix

and

`WaitForSingleObject` for Win.

The Boost library actually uses these functions if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: `WaitForSingleProcess`?? are you sure you don't mean `WaitForSingleObject`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be the `system` function to execute other programs. In your `main.exe` you'd write:

```
system("other.exe");
```

You can also pass command line arguments:

```
#include <stringstream>
...

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "other.exe" << " " << "first-arg" << " " << "second-arg";
system(ss.str().c_str());
```

For this, there is no need to allocate objects with `new` but the arguments have to be parsed in the `other.exe` from `argc` and `argv`. Your `main.exe` will pause until `other.exe` is completed.